# Ubuntu tweak not showing all the menus

Tags: ubuntu-tweak

Ubuntu-Tweak doesn't have the option 
**Startup** which includes

- Session Manager
- Session Control
  and few other options are not there. I am running the latest version available to download. I remember having all those menus in lucid.

for a better difference comparison see the menus in the ubuntu tweak homepage http://ubuntu-tweak.com/ with mine....

[image]

how can I get these option back.

here is the error I get when I run Ubuntu Tweak from terminal

> ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on :1.142:/com/ubuntu_tweak/daemon: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.141" (uid=1000 pid=16550 comm="/usr/bin/python) interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable" member="Introspect" error name="(unset)" requested_reply=0 destination=":1.142" (uid=0 pid=16560 comm="/usr/bin/python))

Update: I installed the same deb on another computer and that has nothing wrong. all the menus are listed fine.

Comment: Hmm.. Really!.. Startup is missing.

Comment: Could you post the output when you run it from the terminal?

Comment: You might want to ask your question on the Ubuntu Tweak Launchpad page, either by 'reporting a bug' (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak/+filebug), or 'asking a question' (https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak/+addquestion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem, may be something wrong with the configuration files in the home folder's hidden files.
Due to some other problem I had to empty my Home Folder and delete all the hidden files and after that Ubuntu Tweak is working fine with all the Options available.

Answer (score 2):

In the latest version (0.5.7) the startup menu has been removed, since it was a duplicate feature of the GNOME Session application.

See the release notes:

http://blog.ubuntu-tweak.com/2010/10/10/ubuntu-tweak-0-5-7-released-hello-ubuntu-maverick.html

Apart from that, you could try uninstalling ubuntu-tweak with

```
sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-tweak
```

reinstall, and see if it works.

Otherwise you should consider a bug report.